# Getting Cellular location data from 3G modem

Tags: 3g

Any idea how to get Cellular location data when using 3G modem? It is more a generic question, but if hardware matters, lets say we are using Huawei E3131 USB modem in HiLink mode and Ubuntu 12.04 or later.

Thanks

Comment: Please, who ever is is trying to answer, do not confuse A-GPS with actual GPS sensor data. A-GPS location is based on the cellular network, not actual GPS satellite communication.

Comment: http://tech.firstpost.com/news-analysis/what-is-a-gps-how-does-it-work-13688.html

Comment: OK, probably I mistaken using A-GPS as a term. My question is how do we get the triangulated location from the cellular network?

Answer (score 2):

I think there is some confusion here. The modem you describe does not have a GPS reciever built in. The only thing you could try is to do a triangulation with cell phone towers to estimate you position.
A GPS lock is not possible.

Comment: That is why I am talking  about A-GPS, not GPS! A-GPS data is based on the cellular network, not on actual GPS sensor.

Comment: http://tech.firstpost.com/news-analysis/what-is-a-gps-how-does-it-work-13688.html

Comment: Sorry, but you are wrong. A-GPS is a network assisted GPS. This means that your GPS has a faster startup time, but you still need the GPS.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assisted_GPS

Comment: OK, lets say it is. I`m wrong in the terms I am using. My question is how do we get the triangulated location from the cellular network?

Comment: OK thats a very good question. I am interested in an answer as well. :)

Answer (score 0):

From the cellular module, the network cell information can be retrieved. IF module is 3gpp supported network cell info can be retrieved by AT command "AT+CGED".

Required cell info required to find out the cell location is:
MCC,MNC,Cell Id,Location Area Code.

Using the third party API you can get the location of the cell connected. As it is done in these sites 
https://cellidfinder.com/ 
http://www.cell2gps.com/

Further you can also go through this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18686888/finding-location-using-mcc-mnc-lac-and-cell-id